# How to get data from OnCompleteListener from Cloud Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get data after a task has been successfully completed and store it in a variable. The code which I've tried is:

```
String user_name;
private void getUserData(){
        FirebaseFirestore db;

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        DocumentReference docref = db.collection("users").document(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid());
        docref.get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                            assert documentSnapshot != null;
                            user_name = documentSnapshot.getString("name");
                        }
                    }
                });


    }

binding.upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                binding.text.setText(user_name);
            }
        });
```

The `setText` for the `text` TextView returns null. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Show us how you "try to use user_name in another function" by adding the corresponding code.

Comment: you are probably looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android)

Comment: Since it's an Asynchronous call, you need to implement a callback or call the function by passing the value of `user_name`.